# STFT not inverted properly without windowing in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, signal-processing, fft

Tensorflow is not reconstructing the original signal when applying the STFT followed by the inverse STFT. The problems arise when the frames of the STFT overlap: It seems like every frame contributes with a weight of 1 regardless of the number of overlapping frames `N = frame_size / frame_step`. As a result, the central part of the signal is `N` times larger than the original. Here is a minimal code to reproduce the error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

size = 2048
frame_length = 512
frame_step = 128
waveform = np.sin(np.arange(size) * 1 / 100)

stft = tf.signal.stft(waveform, frame_length, frame_step, window_fn=None)
inverse_stft = tf.signal.inverse_stft(stft, frame_length, frame_step, window_fn=None)

plt.plot(waveform)
plt.plot(inverse_stft)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

[image: Broken stft --> istft applied to sinusoidal signal]

Notice that I'm using no window. If I put the Hann window, the central part works well but the borders are smoothly going to zero, a related but surprisingly different error. The implementation of scipy works well under all circumstances.

Am I missing something?

Comment: For the amplitude correction, you may have to provide `inverse_stft_window_fn` to your inverse stft but that might require a some windowing function

Comment: I couldn't find the appropriate `inverse_stft_window_fn` for no window so I just assumed I would put no window also in the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Tensorflow has some not perfect implementation that does not work well on boundaries of signals/stfts. And it has not take into the account approriate scaling when `frame_rate =/= frame length`

This could be posted as an issue on their github.

For longer signals (plus taking into account scaling) it looks "good enough":

```
size = 20480
frame_length = 512
frame_step = 256
waveform = np.sin(np.arange(size) * 1 / 100)

stft = tf.signal.stft(waveform, frame_length, frame_step, window_fn=None, pad_end=True)
inverse_stft = tf.signal.inverse_stft(stft, frame_length, frame_step, window_fn=None) / (frame_length / frame_step)

plt.plot(waveform)
plt.plot(inverse_stft)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

[image]

Comment: `For longer signals (plus taking into account scaling) it looks "good enough":` this statement isn't very accurate. Even for shorter signals, you will observe the same result near the start and end of your signal. If you reduce your sample size, you will get the same results. That is most likely related to padding and how other modules like `scipy` handle padding by default.

Comment: @NebiyouYismaw whole point of what I wrote is to look at longer signals, not shorter - for long ones small differences at the boundaries *could* be disregarded - result may be considered as "good enough" for someone, not perfect of course.

Comment: I have posted it on Tensorflow's github and they acknowledged that there's a problem: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53205 . I think that the absence of the scaling factor is just a bug in their code; and once you put that scaling factor back in, the behaviour at the border becomes consistent with what happens using other windows and can be solved manually padding the data on both ends with zeros, as seen here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36616 . (I still believe that there should be at least an option for automatic padding)